# How to clean up snapshots and commits after a period of time in Javers?

Tags: java, javers

I'm setting a auditing system for our application. The tables grow very fast. So I wonder, if there is a mechanism to clean up snapshots and commits after a period of time, for example all snapshots older than 30 days. If it is not possible, could you please suggest other approaches? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Javers provides you any mechanism to delete/update existing commits/snapshots, however you can create your own stored database household procedure and call it by some cron scheduled job. Basically you need only to filter out all `JV_COMMIT` entries by date (older than 30 days), then by `commit` id you can find properties and snapshots, then by snapshot you will find global ids, and just remove them in such order

```
global id -> snapshot -> commit properties -> commit
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean up can be done in the following order:

- DELETE FROM jv_commit_property;
- DELETE FROM jv_snapshot;
- DELETE FROM jv_commit;
- DELETE FROM jv_global_id WHERE owner_id_fk IS NOT NULL;
- DELETE FROM jv_global_id;

Note : You can put the filter clause as per your need which is not considered in the above DB Script.